# Символы в ссылке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Здравствуйте,программно создаю ссылку,следующим методом:
В span (contenteditable="true") вводиться текст,затем при нажатии на кнопку появляется promt туда вводиться ссылка на ресурс,затем ресурс оборачивается тегом.Вот пример

```
        var link_url = prompt('Введите адрес  ресурса:');
        var text_link = $("span").text();
        var link_got = '<a href="' + link_url + '">' + text_link + '</a>';
        $(".selspan").text(link_got);
```

Дело в том,что потом появляется вот такое

```
&lt;a href="https://mail.ru/"&gt;Почтовый сервис&lt;/a&gt;
```

Как с этим бороться,как сделать < вместо &lt

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм, может потому что `text()` - это вставка текста, HTML-сущности превращаются в [мнемоники](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B2_HTML), а не HTML-кода?

> Use the `html()`, Luke!

```js
$(function() {
  $('#getLink').on('click', function() {
    var text_link = $("#textForLink").text(), link_url, link_got;
    
    if(text_link == '')
      return;
    
    link_url = prompt('Введите адрес  ресурса:');
    link_got = '<a href="' + link_url + '">' + text_link + '</a>';
    
    $("#textSpan").text(link_got);
    $("#htmlSpan").html(link_got);
  });
});
```

```css
#textForLink:focus{
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Text for link</h2>
<span contenteditable="true" id='textForLink'></span>
<br />
<input type='button' id='getLink' value='Get link!' />
<h3>Result</h3>
<h4>Text</h4>
<span id='textSpan'></span>
<h4>HTML</h4>
<span id='htmlSpan'></span>
```

Но это какой-то сложный путь, не проще через `prompt()` попросить и текст ввести?

Answer (score 1):

Либо использовать метод `html` вместо `text`, что, кстати, небезовасно; либо просто сделать по-человечекси без превращения всего в текст:

```
var link_url = prompt('Введите адрес  ресурса:');
$(".selspan").html($("<a>").html($("span")).attr("href", link_url));
```